# Prevent Multi Group Row Selection

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have slick grid set up with groups and row selection. Is there an easy way to not allow row selection between groups? Or is there an event fired before the actual row selection is being made so that i can do some self validation to ensure no cross group selection is being made?

**Edit**

I do think i found one way using the onSelectedRowsChanged event.

```
              if(args.rows.length > 1){
                  var currentSelection = mainGrid.getData().getItem(args.rows[args.rows.length - 1]),
                      previousSelection = mainGrid.getData().getItem(args.rows[args.rows.length - 2]); 

                  //Prevents selection from across groups 
                  if(currentSelection.vesselName != previousSelection.vesselName) {
                      var temp = args.rows;
                          temp.pop();

                        mainGrid.setSelectedRows(temp);
                  }
              }
```

Comment: I find your question not really clear... Can you provide some examples or update your question? What do you mean by row selection exactly anyway? And are you talking about multi-group, or single column grouping?

Comment: I have them grouped by one column. My goal is to try and only allow multi row selection, but not across multiple groups. For example If i have it grouped by a column called title and I have one group called Apples and one called Pears if i want to select and edit I want them to be able to chose multiples of apple to edit or multiples of pear, but not both pears and apples.